# Can we make a map in C++, with the value as a function of key?

Tags: c++, stl

In C++ STL, the map is used to map the key to a value. I want to know whether we can do this mapping based on some function say

> map< int, string > M;
>   and value=binary_representation(key) ?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Surely, you can put those key-value pairs into the map.

Comment: Please tell me how to do it ? But it should not be done explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean?  Is `for (auto k : keys) table[k] = func(k);` too explicit?  Wrap that into a factory function if you want.

Comment: Yes, something like this would suffice.

Comment: Also,we do have comparator function in std::sort(). So, I am just asking can we have an extra argument which does all this conversion and then the insertion is done in the map. Or do we need to convert the keys into corresponding values and then insert into the map?

Comment: @5gon12eder your comment is the most appropriate one, could you please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert arbitrary (*key*, *value*) pairs into a `std::map` so you can certainly insert (*x*<sub>*i*</sub>, *f*(*x*<sub>*i*</sub>)) pairs for a function *f* and any *x*<sub>1</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*n*</sub> you like, provided that the types match.

The straight-forward way to do this might be to use a `for` loop.

```
for (const auto& k : keys)
  mapping[k] = f(k);
```

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace /* anonymous */
{

  std::string
  my_function(const int n)
  {
    const auto size = static_cast<int>(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int));
    std::string bits {};
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      {
        const auto bit = (n >> (size - i - 1)) & 1;
        bits += (bit ? '1' : '0');
      }
    return bits;
  }

}


int
main()
{
  std::map<int, std::string> reprs {};
  for (auto k = -3; k < 10; ++k)
    reprs[k] = my_function(k);
  for (const auto& kv : reprs)
    std::cout << std::setw(4) << kv.first << "  =>  " << kv.second << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
  -3  =>  11111111111111111111111111111101
  -2  =>  11111111111111111111111111111110
  -1  =>  11111111111111111111111111111111
   0  =>  00000000000000000000000000000000
   1  =>  00000000000000000000000000000001
   2  =>  00000000000000000000000000000010
   3  =>  00000000000000000000000000000011
   4  =>  00000000000000000000000000000100
   5  =>  00000000000000000000000000000101
   6  =>  00000000000000000000000000000110
   7  =>  00000000000000000000000000000111
   8  =>  00000000000000000000000000001000
   9  =>  00000000000000000000000000001001
```

If you want to follow the advice of favoring algorithms over raw loops, you could use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) together with a [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) to do the trick.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace /* anonymous */
{

  std::string
  my_function(int);  // as above

}

int
main()
{
  std::vector<int> keys(13);
  std::iota(keys.begin(), keys.end(), -3);
  std::map<int, std::string> reprs {};
  const auto generator = [](const int n){
    return std::make_pair(n, my_function(n));
  };
  std::transform(keys.cbegin(), keys.cend(),
                 std::inserter(reprs, reprs.begin()),
                 generator);
  for (const auto& kv : reprs)
    std::cout << std::setw(4) << kv.first << "  =>  " << kv.second << '\n';
}
```

However, I'm not sure if the use of iterators and algorithms really helps the readability of the code in this simple case.  The use of the `keys` vector is a bit of an abomination here.  If you have Boost, you could replace it by a [`boost::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could do, but it would be completely pointless. It would just be an inferior `std::set<int>` that doesn't properly guarantee the invariant and consumes a higher memory usage and runtime for absolutely no benefit whatsoever (unless you really wanted a cache).

Comment: Having a cache for the results of (a more complicated) function isn't all that pointless, however.

Comment: "Do I need to write the whole template for it ?" What? I don't understand this question? What is "writing a template"?

Comment: @5gon12eder yes, an implicit function which converts the key to corresponding value and then the map.insert() is done. Is it possible, then how ?

Comment: We can have comparator function in std::sort().
So, I am just asking can we have an extra argument which does all this conversion and then the insertion is done in the map.